# "Visualforce Page" Lightning Component in Napili Template for Communities

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, napili, lightning-community

I am trying to load visualforce page in "Visualforce Page" lightning component in napili template for communities .
[image]

The issue is that all of the hyperlinks of visualforce page has been updated with "one/one.app" as prefix as shown below:

**Previous Url:**
/customers/userProfile?u=0059A000000N61eQAC

**New Url:**
/one/one.app#/alohaRedirect/customers/userProfile?u=0059A000000N61eQAC

Can anyone please confirm why this is happening and what could be the possible solution for this?

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me .Create a component that uses iframe tab and use your visualforce in that .This is a workaround for issue you are facing .

Comment: That will add a new issue. If I go with that approach then correct content will load but top url will never change.